# How to increase video resolution

Tags: video, conversion, resolution, avi

I have this  356MB .rmvb file that I converted to .avi and it became 2Gb.
But the size is still the same, and the quality still sucks. Is there any tool that could increase the resolution and quality of this video so that it would fit with my monitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Nope!**

What you're wanting is getting information from nowhere - CSI style "increase... increase... enhance.. zoom in on that guy's watch... enhance... we have our killer, and look at that letter he's carrying! That's his home address, let's go!" is entirely impossible.

It may be possible to slightly increase the quality, but nowhere near what you want. Sorry, but if you want better quality footage, you can't get it from low quality footage.

Comment: I guess I'll just watch it on smaller screens:)

Comment: Or from further away, then you won't notice the lack of quality as much :)

Comment: What about compressed sensing? Wouldn't that be able to upsample the video?

Comment: @marcusw: Maybe. You'd get something out of it, but whether it'd be enough of a difference to be worthwhile even attempting, I don't know. (I don't pretend to understand how it works, but I can't imagine it not being computationally very expensive)

Comment: @marcusw - compressed sensing is one thing, fractal compression another (the compressed data is resolution independent so can be expanded to any size) but as Phoshi says, the algorithm is *guessing* new information. You don't get more detail - if you're lucking you some sharper lines. Also, more sophisticated compression means slow compression, and sometimes slower decompression too.